# Airflow Revision already exists

Tags: airflow

I have ran airflow initdb for the second time and received the following error:

```
alembic.util.exc.CommandError: Can't locate revision identified by '9635ae0956e7'
```

So I understand that I need to remove the already registered version, but I cannot seem to find it. when I open the mysql cli (using sudo mysql) I only see 4 dbs: information_schema ,mysql, performance_schem, sys

How to do I remove this revision and start fresh?

Answer (score 2):

So one solution, that worked for me, is to remove the file airflow.db under $ARIFLOW_HOME/ and run airflow initdb again. This recreates the file with a new revision